# How do I properly handle private python package dependencies?

Tags: python-3.x, package

FYI, I'm quite new to Python and it's packaging and dependency tools seem confusing.

I am going to be writing series of Python packages that support Dags running in Apache Airflow. As these packages share some common functionality I want to extract the commonalities out into separate supporting modules. In turn, these supporting modules will rely on at least two other supporting modules. All of the modules/packages in question will be published as source distributions on an internal repository.

Is there a way for me to install the main packages such that **all** of the direct and indirect dependencies are installed from the private repo?

I have made use of **install_requires** in setup.py to install modules available via Pypi and it seems like I could do something like this to achieve my goals, however this seems like it could get messy when I need to update say the version of the indirect dependencies. Is there a better way that I can handle this? Would adding the dependencies to **requirements.txt** with an **--extra-index** argument be a valid approach?

The hierarchy of dependencies can be represented loosely as:

```
MainPackage
  -> SupportingPackage
    -> CommonUtilites
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use a git repository as a Python package source.

Just add `git+{REPO_LINK}@{TAG_OR_SHA1}` in `requirements.txt` and just `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

See [How to add git source in requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56989529/how-to-add-git-source-in-requirements-txt/56990990#56990990).