# How to add git source in requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, package

I would like to install a certain package from a private git repository. This is possible using `pip install git+<REPO_LINK>`. However, I would like to `pip install -r requirements.txt` all of my packages at the same time without having to specify which one comes from Pypi and private repo.

I have tried adding a configuration in `~/.config/pip/pip.conf`

```
[global]
find-links =
    git+<REPO_LINK>
```

but this happened when running `pip install -r requirements.txt`:

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement my-package==0.1`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution for it [at this doc](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#git).

`pip install git+<REPO_LINK>#egg=<PACKAGE_NAME>`

When I run `pip freeze`, the package I have just installed is printed like this:

`git+<REPO_LINK>#egg=<PACKAGE_NAME>`

Add it to  your `requirements.txt` so `pip install -r requirements.txt` install this specific package so as public ones from Pypi.

:)